# Bluetooth does not scan without GPS android 10

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-10.0

I try to scan bluetooth device on xiaomi redmi 9 android 10 but if I don't open GPS, it does not work. I searched about these problem, and I found that if we use BLE, we have to use GPS otherwise we don't have to use GPS. I don't use BLE but it does not scan.

Here my permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

Here my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView myAwesomeTextView ;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
 


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myAwesomeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
  
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bluetoothAdapter.enable();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();


    }


 private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
           
            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                
                myAwesomeTextView.setText("start");
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            
                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                //bluetooth device found

                //device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                //myAwesomeTextView.setText("found");
                if (deviceName != null){
                    myAwesomeTextView.setText("Found device " + deviceName);
                    

                }
                
            }
        }
    };



}
```

Comment: Is ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION really needed? Please try without.

Comment: @blackapps it does not work both case if I delete the permission.

Comment: It looks as if this is the same as not showing ssid of wifi access point without location permission. As showing the name would tell location.

Comment: @blackapps actually I have no so much kwnoledege about android and bluetooth programming. So, I don't know how to solve it, can you provide me a more detailed solution ?

Comment: I thought you solved it by using fine location. I dont know what you wanna solve further.

Comment: @blackapps it does not work even I add fine location permission. But if I turn on GPS, it absolutely works.

Comment: Ok. I tried your code and can only confirm what you said.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for your effort, it is a big step because you confirm the problem is not about my device, it is general problem.